# Laravel logout function is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, angular5, laravel-passport

I am creating a project using laravel as the backend and angular 5 angular 5 as the front end. While accessing laravel functions through API calls from angular for logout it gives an error message

> exception:"BadMethodCallException"
>   file:"/path/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php" line:96 message:"Method logout does not exist."`

```
public function getlogout() {

    if (Auth::logout()) {
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

}
```

please, someone, help me as I am new to laravel.

Comment: You don't need a logout function on laravel if you are using it as a backend you will only need to logout on the angular side by deleting the token

Comment: I need to log out using laravel as I am using remember_token which need to be modified after every logout automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the laravel-passport and do so:

```
public function logout()
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    $user->token()->revoke();
    event(new Logout($user));

    return return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
}
```